# Why test char equals the same char?

Tags: javascript

Reading through some JavaScript from an ecommerce hosting company and came across this:

```
function add_wishlist()
{
    if ('1' == '1') // <-- What is this?
    {
        window.open('addtowishlist.asp?itemid=137','popup','height=300,width=550,location=no,scrollbars=no,menubars=no,toolbars=no,resizable=yes');
    }
    else
    {
        document.add.action = "add_cart.asp?action=addWishList";
        document.add.submit();
    }
}
```

From my basic understanding of JavaScript, the `==` equality operator will attempt type conversion if required then compare the values. In this case, the character `1` compared to the character `1`, which seems like it will *always* be true.

I feel I might be missing something because why have an `else` clause if the code is always unreachable? This appears to have been purposeful code as I can't imagine it's easy to accidentally write this comparison. However, there does appear to be some inherent sloppiness to this code since JavaScript programmers should be in the habit of writing curly braces on the same line to avoid any possible semicolon insertion quirks...

Am I missing something here? Or is it just sloppy code?

Comment: the page is generated by a serverside language. one of the `'1'` in the equation is probably generated by a preprocessor directive like `if(<%=ActionID%> = '1')`

Comment: *"However, there does appear to be some inherent sloppiness to this code since JavaScript programmers should be in the habit of writing curly braces on the same line to avoid any possible semicolon insertion quirks..."* That only applies when using `return` with an object initializer. Sufficiently edge-case that if someone prefers the older, much-easier-to-move-code-around style, there's no good reason for them to stop using it.

Comment: @Banana's theory makes good sense.

Comment: @Banana Good idea, however this code is in the user editable templates, so this section is not touched by their ASP engine before serving.

Comment: @SnakeDoc if its a template then you got the answer right there. its a template and you need to change it according to your needs, if thats the case then it doesnt really matter what is in the condition since its not intended to remain there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes always true statements are used by developers to temporarily disable a branch of code. IMO, comments are a better way to do this.

Another possibility is that this is code generated by a tool, and this is the emitted code they got when disabling a feature.

Comment: JavaScript has booleans though, so a `if (true)` would of worked. Are you suggesting this comparison is just a poorly done "fix" or something?

Comment: Yeah, `if (true)` is the more common approach. This is just sloppy code.